# Swift - Merge two arrays whilst removing keys duplicates and adding array values together

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, array-merge

I have two arrays that look something like the below example. What I would like to do is merge the two together. If their keys are equal remove the duplicate and add both of their values together.

Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks!!

**Current Code:**

```
struct Example: Codable {
    var key: String
    var value: Int
}

var first: [Example] = []
var second: [Example] = []

first.append(Example(key: "1", value: 10))
first.append(Example(key: "2", value: 10))
first.append(Example(key: "3", value: 10))

second.append(Example(key: "2", value: 10))
second.append(Example(key: "3", value: 10))
second.append(Example(key: "4", value: 10))


let merged = Array(Dictionary([first, second].joined().map { ($0.key, $0)}, uniquingKeysWith: { $1 }).values)
```

**Currently Prints**

```
Example(key: "3", value: 10)
Example(key: "1", value: 10)
Example(key: "2", value: 10)
Example(key: "4", value: 10)
```

**What I would like do to:**

```
Example(key: "3", value: 20)
Example(key: "1", value: 10)
Example(key: "2", value: 20)
Example(key: "4", value: 10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there!

In the `uniqueKeysWith` parameter, you should create a new `Example` that contains the same key, and the sum of the two parameters' values:

```
let merged = Array(Dictionary([first, second].joined().map { ($0.key, $0)}, uniquingKeysWith: { Example(key: $0.key, value: $0.value + $1.value) }).values)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!! 